# Unnecessary type juggling to define Data.Void (package "void" on Hackage)?

Tags: haskell

The [void](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.5.5) package claims to provide an uninhabitable type called `Void`, which is defined as follows -

```
newtype Void = Void Void
```

How is this definition any better than using something simpler? Say -

```
data Void
```

If my understanding is correct, both the data types contain only bottom values. However the latter is much easier to understand.

**EDIT**: Okay so I understand Daniel's answer below. However I thought of another possibly simpler way to do this while remaining Haskell98 compatible. We can use an Abstract data type and expose no constructors to the user.

```
module Data.Void (Void) where
  data Void = Void
```

Now only code in Data.Void module can construct a Void, however since we know it *doesn't*, the Void datatype is effectively uninhabited.

Would that work or am I missing something here?

Comment: "Now only code in Data.Void module can construct a Void" that is one module too many.

Comment: Well yeah.. I understand that now, after reading [Carl's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261490/unnecessary-type-juggling-to-define-data-void-package-void-on-hackage?noredirect=1#comment11678217_9261699) :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From description for the void package on Hackage: "A **Haskell 98** logically uninhabited data type" (my emphasis). Declaring `Void` as simply `data Void` would require either Haskell 2010 or the "EmptyDataDecls" language extension and thus would not be "Haskell 98".

**EDIT**

[Here is a page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Empty_type) on the Haskell Wiki that describes exactly this situation.

Comment: Great, so I can use my own definition if haskell98 compatibility is not important to me. Thanks!

Comment: I added another possible (and simpler) way to do this in Haskell98. What do you think of that?

Comment: @AnupamJain That's not simpler or even correct. The only reason the void package exists is to have a type with bottoms as the only possible inhabitants. Failing to export a constructor doesn't mean the constructor doesn't exist. The newtype formulation proves that only bottoms can inhabit the type. This is important for making the absurd function in the module typecheck, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Your implementation is still incomplete because you do not have the absurd function:

```
absurd :: Void -> a
```

Void is supposed to be an initial object in Haskell, which is why you need the absurd function.  I find the implementation of absurd in the void package to be very elegant and appropriate:

```
absurd (Void a) = absurd a
```

This definition is reminiscent of the logical analogy of Void to the False premise from which any conclusion can be derived.  It even uses the logical fallacy of referencing itself to prove itself, which is logically ... absurd.